# Joomla administrator page not entirely loading

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I'm struggling pushing my Joomla website to the remote server. When I login into the administration page everything works fine, but after then the configuration panel isn't loaded properly: [image]

The navbar isn't loaded and I can't do anything but changing users informations. I've already checked the file permissions (files permissions 644 and folders permissions 755). The debug bar doesn't show any error (error reporting too).

EDIT:
The homepage is broken too, It doesn't load all of the content of the page and as I can see I've the same problem with all the pages of my website, it seems like the users don't have the right permissions to see the categories because I receive this error:
[image]

Joomla version: 3.9.28
PHP version: 7.3.29
SQL version: 5.5.5-10.4.20-MariaDB
The website in local environment is working fine.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Do you have any errors showing in your browser console?

Comment: No, I can't see any error in the browser console. @Lodder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts I found the solution. The best way to migrate a website from a local environment to live is through Akeeba Backups.
Please follow this guide if you encounter the same problem as mine:
https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/how-to-move-a-joomla-site-from-localhost-to-live-server

I think the real issue was about file and folders permissions, with Akeeba backups went everything went smoothly.

## Use Akeeba Backup to Move the Joomla Site

To do this, you will be using the Akeeba Backup Joomla extension first to take a backup of your website (root files and database) and then Akeeba Kickstart to restore the backup to the live server. The transfer process consists of the following steps.

### Step 1: Download and Install Akeeba Backup

First of all, you need to download the Akeeba Backup extension. Once you have downloaded the latest version in .zip format, login to your Joomla site administrator dashboard. From the dashboard, click on Extensions > Manage > Install. Here, under the Upload Package File option, browse and select the downloaded file. This will upload and install Akeeba Backup on your site.

### Step 2: Backup Your Files

After the successful installation of Akeeba Backup, the next step is to take a backup of your site. Simply do this by: on top of the dashboard, select Components and then Akeeba Backup
Click Backup Now. This will download a .jpa file to your computer.

### Step 3: Download Akeeba Kickstart

Download Akeeba Kickstart to your computer.

### Step 4: Upload the Files to Your New Server

From your hosting control panel or FTP client, select the destination web root directory and upload the .jpa file from step 2 and kickstart.php from step 3 to the new server.

### Step 5: Create a Database on Your Hosting Company’s Server

From your cPanel or server’s database management system, create a new empty database for your live site.

### Step 6: Run the Kickstart Installer to Install Your Site on the New Server.

All you have to do now is from the browser go to (URL of your live site)/kickstart.php. You now need to follow the guide and install the website in live environment.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http(s)://your-site/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules&view=modules

Select Administrator in the filter and see which backend modules have been disabled; you should see a screen like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the page in my website with the same statuses as yours, so I think my modules are set right.

Comment: In that case, have a look at what @pe7er wrote.  It may be that your backend login account does not have the required viewing level access to see the backend modules.

Comment: Sozzled, @lapo would not have been pinged by your comment. I have effectively pinged them, now, for you. Please see [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/352329) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an **issue** in your web site **with Viewing Access Levels**.

By default the **administrator Modules** Menu, Title and Toolbar have been assigned to the "Special" group. It looks like the User Goups of your User Account doesn't have the right Viewing Access Level ("Special").

To fix it:

- Check to which **User Groups** your User Account have been assigned to.
- Check the Users > **Viewing Access Levels** if that User Group has been assigned to the "Special" viewing level.

Comment: I've checked the User Group of my user and it is "Super Users" which is related to the "Special" viewing level. Any other idea?